# Get user informations in VueJS with a NestJs backend

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, passport.js, nestjs

So i'm creating an NestJS API with a VueJS frontend. I have used passportjs to serialize user info, you can read it below :

```
@Injectable()
export class SessionSerializer extends PassportSerializer {
  serializeUser(user: any, done: (err: Error, user: any) => void): any {
    done(null, user);
  }
  deserializeUser(payload: any, done: (err: Error, payload: string) => void): any {
    done(null, payload);
  }

}
```

My API is working fine, but i don't know how to retrieve user data in my frontend app. I have this code in one of my view, but i have nothing in my User object.

```
<script>
  import UserDataService from 'src/services/UserDataService';

  export default {
    name: 'UserProfile',
    data () {
      return {
        
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getUserData: function () {
        let self = this
       UserDataService.getUser()
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
            self.$set(this, "user", response.data.user)
            console.log(response.data.user.id)
          })
          .catch((errors) => {
            console.log(errors)
          })
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      this.getUserData()
    }
  }
</script>
```

For information, i'm using axios.

It's a project that i do in order to learn how to do API, and i have chosen VueJS because apparently it's more "easy" that Angular. If you have advices, i'll gladly take them.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing the `user` property in the `data` function.

As per the documentation:

> Since Vue doesn’t allow dynamically adding root-level reactive properties, you have to initialize Vue instances by declaring all root-level reactive data properties upfront, even with an empty value.

You should add it like this:

```js
data () {
 return {
   user: {} // you may initialize it with the value that you think it's more convenient
 }
}
```

Also there's no need for the `let self = this` because the arrow function is already taking care of using the context of its containing block, namely the `getUserData` function.

Having that said there's also no need to use `this.$set` in this case because this type of property declaration **is** reactive (`Vue.set` or its local version `this.$set` are generally used in cases where you need to make changes to properties that cannot be detected by Vue's reactivity system).

You can just do:

```js
getUserData: function () {
  UserDataService.getUser()
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
      this.user = response.data.user
      console.log(response.data.user.id)
    })
    .catch((errors) => {
      console.log(errors)
    })
}
```

Check out the docs for more info about Vue and its [reactivity system](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html).